# Why don't you feel gravity the same way you feel a car's acceleration?

Tags: forces, gravity, reference-frames, acceleration, equivalence-principle

If you are in an accelerating car or spaceship you feel an apparent force pushing you backwards, which as I understand is due to your own body's inertia (it wants to keep its current velocity but the vehicle's velocity keeps changing as it accelerates). You don't feel this backwards/upwards force with gravity.

Is it because gravity acts on your whole body equally? In contrast, if you are in a car technically only the part in contact with the seat would be accelerating at the same rate as the car (and the rest of your body will be pushed back due to wanting to keep its own inertia)? While with gravity every point of your body has the same inertia so you don't feel an opposite push?

If you were enormously tall, would your head keep feeling this backward force as the gravity acting on your body would no longer be uniform?

Comment: It _might_ also be the case that _in the first half_ you're confused with feeling a jerk with feeling a force. Think about it!

Comment: For the last question, are you talking about tidal forces?

Comment: But you do!?...

Comment: The premise in the title is incorrect. We do feel gravity, so there is not question.

Comment: Yes, I've phrased it wrongly I believe. What I meant was that in a spaceship for example that accelerates upwards you feel a force pulling you downwards, but on Earth even though gravity acts downwards you feel a force pulling you down, rather than one pushing you up. In newtonian mechanics you always consider the real forces rather than the fictitious ones, so why the exception with gravity which seems to behave like an inertial force?

Comment: "You don't feel this backwards/upwards force with gravity." You don't feel the pressure on your feet when you're standing, the pressure on your butt when sitting, or the pressure on your back when lying down?

Comment: @Veirian: what's happened here is merely that you're facing in the wrong direction :-) In a spaceship accelerating at 1g towards Alpha Centauri, you feel "your weight" directed away from Alpha Centauri. On the planet Earth, you feel a "your weight" towards the centre of the Earth. Your mistake is merely to equate "down" with "towards Alpha Centauri" when you compare "gravity acting downwards" with "accelerating towards Alpha Centauri". It would be correct to equate "downwards" with "Earth" when comparing "gravity acting downwards" with "accelerating away from Earth".

Comment: So, when a car accelerates forwards, you feel some fraction of "your weight" directed backwards (unless your car does 0-60 in 2.7 seconds, in which case it would be your full weight of 1g). This feels like the back of the seat pressing on your back, in *exactly* the same way that gravity feels like the base of the seat pressing on your butt. Of course the car only does this for a few seconds, whereas gravity is 24/7. If a car corners sharply and you aren't braced, you "fall" sideways away from the corner, because the car accelerated towards the corner. Etc.

Comment: It's understandable that you've never been to outer-space, or in any other microgravity or zero-g environment, but I assure you the force of gravity is a formidable force that you are crushed with every second of every day.  If you spent even five minutes in zero gravity it would be extremely difficult to ignore the force of gravity when you were suddenly reacquainted with it.

Comment: I think it is an excellent question, and I understand it is susceptible to making the wrong premise if you are uncertain about the basics of the underlying physics. I've tried to rewrite it in the hope that voters can see its value. The fact that it has received so much attention while so many answers still have inaccuracies shows that the question is interesting at the very least. If they nonetheless decide to close it on the grounds that the edit leads to a question that is too deviating from the original, then that's fair enough, and Ill repost the question and answer as a new one.

Answer (score 28):

They are both exactly the same and feel exactly the same.

In fact, they don't feel like anything. Gravitational force and centrifugal "force" or other inertial "forces" cannot be "felt" at all. Because (in the reference frames where they appear) they act on every single particle in your body at the same time.

When you jump from a plane you are speeded up by the gravitational force. Each particle in your body is. The only reason you don't feel it is because all the particles of your body move *equally*. But hit a bird with your arm on the way down, and suddenly your arm is slowed down and not keeping the same speed as the rest of your body. You feel that as your tissue molecules being stretched and moved *relative to each other*.

**Feeling and pain in your body comes not from force acting on your body parts but from relative motion between body particles.**

That's the key. It is never force, you feel. It is always only the *effect* of the force you can feel. It is the *acceleration* or *relative velocity* between body parts and particles you feel. Only. So the way we feel and experience forces is from how they cause changes in the otherwise equal motion of particles within us.

- You can certainly feel gravity when you hit the ground. The first-impacting particles are slowed down suddenly while the rest of the particles are still moving downwards.
- Likewise, you can feel the centrifugal effect only when squeezed towards the car door. Or when your seat pulls in you. Your body tends to keep moving straight due to its inertia, so when the car turns then it is not you who is being forced or pushed or pulled - it is the car that is moving. If you jumped off from the seat, and then the car turned, you wouldn't feel a thing.

Inside the turning car, it looks like you moving towards the car door because your brain tricks you into assuming your surroundings to be stationary. But in reality ti is the car door which is moving towards you. It is an illusion. You are not being influenced at all - not until the car door hits you, that is, and only then do you feel anything.

---

*Sidenote: As far as I'm aware, the very fact that gravity was observed to "feel" and behave just like any fictitous pseudo-force such as centrifugal forces and Coriolis forces etc. lead to a belief that perhaps gravity is a fictitious force as well. Perhaps we are living within a non-inertial reference frame. This has turned out to be explained via gravitational fields in general relativity.*

*So, suddenly, just like the centrifugal "force" is nothing but an illusion it seems that gravity is nothing but an illusion too. (They may be illusions, but their effects are of course clearly still very, very real - what I mean by illusion is that they are inertial tendencies rather than actual forces; we are just tricked to think of them as forces.)*

Comment: Excellent! We don't feel forces. We experience relative accelerations and infer a force. Could we also experience strains due to signals from nerves? Consider sore joints from standing which hurt less when we lie or sit.

Comment: Thanks! So when you are in a spaceship that accelerates, your body isn't accelerating so it slams against the back of the ship? But then if your entire body was somehow able to accelerate with the same rate as the ship on its own, you'd essentially feel weightless in the ship, correct (which would be the same as gravity).

Comment: @Veirian Yes, exactly. That is essentially what gravity does: makes everything accelerate equally.

Comment: @BillN To be specific, what I've described here regarding feeling and pain is mainly mechanical. I believe we could consider thermodynamic feeling and pain as another topics, where microscopic differences in vibrations etc. constitute what we feel

Comment: It might be more accurate to say that the reason why you feel gravity during acceleration -- falling off a cliff, say -- is not just because the gravitational effect is increasing your body's momentum, but -- equally important -- your body's inertia is resisting that increase. We don't 'feel' gravity normally, because it only registers on our senses when we accelerate or decelerate (within a gravity field). In our normal existence we are not doing either. Once we have been accelerated - in a fast car, say - we are moving at a constant velocity once more, albeit faster, so again feel no motion.

Comment: @Ed999 Even when we are accelerating we still might not feel it *if every part of our body accelerates equally *. That's is the effect by gravity.

Comment: @Veirian: Also note that, when you lie down on the floor (a hard surface), you can feel your back pushing against the floor (and vice versa) - you feel the compression of your tissues. If you think about it, it's not that different from what happens in the car - except that the acceleration of the car is often not constant, so how much you sink into the seat changes. The same happens when you're not lying down, except in a different direction, but it's perhaps less noticeable because you're more used to it.

Comment: We feel gravity all the time. We just don't notice it because it is our default condition. However, as soon as gravity changes, either because we are in free fall, or outside the gravity well or floating in a liquid, we are certainly aware of the change. And then, when gravity returns we will be aware of it as well, until we get used to it all over again. Of course it is the effect of the force rather than the force itself that we feel, but it isn't true that we cannot perceive the effect of gravity because it acts on our entire body. We even have special gravitic sensors in our inner ear.

Comment: @terdon You could argue that we feel it all the time but are used to it so we don't notice, yes. I guess that depends on the exact idea of "feel". But are you saying that we can detect gravity even during freefall? Such as when levitating within a space station? I've not heard of a "gravitic sensor" in our inner ear before - do you have a link by any chance (all I find when googling is Star Treck references...)

Comment: @Steeven I am being facetious. It's a "gravitic sensor" in the sense that it works via gravity, not that it can actually sense gravity itself. I'm referring to the structure in our inner ears that tells us which way is up. That works through gravity. I did not mean to imply we can sense the _actual_ force itself nor that we can detect it when in free-fall, sorry.

Comment: @terdon Ah, I get it :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is incorrect. You *do* feel acceleration directly through your vestibular system, but there is more going on. I have attempted to explain this properly in my answer. In my opinion, talking about fictious forces or general relativity leads to confusion. Even in conventional physics, gravity can be described as a pure acceleration, and it is perceived as such.

Answer (score 6):

You DO feel the acceleration of gravity.  For instance, as I sit here typing this, I feel my butt pressing into the seat of my chair with a force of 1 g.  If I stand up, I will feel my feet pressing on the floor with the same force; likewise if I go do a yoga headstand, I will feel that 1 g acting in the opposite direction.  However, you may not NOTICE the force unless you choose to pay attention to it.

The reason you notice accelerations in a car more is that your brain tends to react more to changes in stimuli rather than to steady values.  If you're driving on a winding road, the acceleration you experience changes from moment to moment, as the acceleration vector shifts from side to side.  Make the same sort of turns if the road is banked just right, or in a light plane where you can bank for yourself, and you don't experience those side-to-side accelerations, only a much less noticable increase in the force acting vertically with respect to your body. That is, you just sit a bit heavier.

Comment: There's also a clue in the units. We say colloquially that "I feel a force of 1g". But force isn't measured in g, it's measured in Newtons. The dimensions of g are m/s^2, and what you feel in your butt is precisely an *acceleration* of 1g.

Comment: This is incorrect. You do not feel the force of gravity. If you did then astronauts in the ISS would feel it. The force of gravity on astronauts in the ISS is about 90% what it is on the surface of the earth. Gravity doesn’t stop in space, what makes you feel different in orbit is the absence of contact forces, not the absence of gravity.

Comment: @Dale: Please read what I wrote, not what you apparently think I wrote: "You DO feel the acceleration of gravity."  I can take that same light plane I mentioned, and fly a path in which I will (momentarily) not feel that acceleration (see also "Vomit Comet"), even though I'm obviously in the same gravitational field.  (Note: better to do this in a sailplane, unless you have an engine certified for inverted flight.)

Comment: I read what you wrote and it is incorrect. You wrote “You DO feel the acceleration of gravity” which is wrong. The correct statement would be “You DO NOT feel the acceleration of gravity”. Your example of the vomit comet supports my claim and contradicts yours. Gravity is still present and the acceleration still happens, but you do not feel it. The sensation of not “feeling gravity” is explained by the absence of the contact forces. Therefore what you feel is the contact forces, not gravity. Your answer is factually incorrect.

Comment: @SteveJessop When sitting in a chair, your butt has an acceleration of exactly 0m/s^2. You don't feel acceleration in your butt, since there is none (it's stationary). You feel the normal force from the chair. An astronaut on the ISS is still affected by gravity (0.9g) but doesn't "feel" it, since they don't experience a normal force that gives the sensation of weight.

Comment: @Dale:  So the nerve endings in my butt are just imagining the sensation?  Sure...

Comment: @jamesqf the nerves in your butt feel contact forces, not gravity. Right now you have both the contact force and gravity, so you cannot distinguish which you are feeling. Remove the contact force and keep gravity, the sensation goes away. Keep the contact force and remove gravity, the sensation remains. Therefore, the sensation is due to the contact force not gravity. Your statement is wrong.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie: 0 in what frame of reference? General relativity says that the astronaut in orbit is in an (approximately) inertial frame of reference, and I'm not.

Comment: @Dale: And those contact forces are caused by what, pray tell?  I likewise don't describe how the sensory nerves work, the action of ion channels in propagating spikes to the brain, or how the brain turns those into something I percevive as sensation.  Why don't you stop playing stupid linguistic games and do something useful?

Comment: @jamesqf you cannot get rid of a physical counterexample by whining about “linguistic games”. The counterexamples physically disprove your statement. The sensation can be present without gravity and absent with gravity so it is not caused by gravity.

Comment: On physicsSE, could you please use correct units? A force isn't an acceleration, and cannot be described with g. The rest of the answer looks good otherwise.

Comment: @Dale: Sorry, but it's your physical example, or your interpretation of it, that is wrong, simply because your decision to play games.  I feel the sensation in my butt, which (unless I've been abducted by aliens, and am writing this in a flying saucer accelerating at 9.8 m/s^2) is due to gravity.

Comment: @jamesqf It isn’t due to gravity. It is due to the contact force. If you and your chair get pushed off an elevator shaft there is just as much gravity but the contact force disappears as does the sensation. So gravity is not a sufficient condition. If you and your chair go to interstellar space and you burn your rocket engines then there is no gravity but the contact force is there as is the sensation. So gravity is not necessary. Gravity is neither necessary nor sufficient, it is not the cause. Non-tidal gravity is a fictitious force and like all fictitious forces it does not cause anything

Comment: @Dale: "The sensation can be present without gravity and absent with gravity" does not imply that the sensation can never be caused by gravity, does it?

Comment: @Eric Duminil gravity can certainly be present but its mere presence does not make it a cause. If I stick a thermometer in a drone and claim that it detects malaria then I could fly it over Myanmar and over Stockholm and call that evidence supporting my claim. But if someone were to fly over a hot place without malaria or a cooler place with malaria then that would show that it detects temperature and not malaria. Then even when we do fly over warm places with malaria we would still say that the high reading is caused by the temperature, not the malaria.

Comment: @Dale: And in my case, the contact force is due to what, exactly?  The acceleration of the flying saucer that abducted me?  Or maybe I'm in orbit, and there are elastic bands strapping me down in my chair?

Comment: @jamesqf the contact force is due to the compression of the tissue, e.g. Hooke’s law. In your case gravity is also present, but as explained earlier it is not the cause of the sensation since it is neither necessary nor sufficient. Do you not understand that necessary causes must be necessary and sufficient causes must be sufficient so something that is neither necessary nor sufficient cannot be a cause?

Comment: @Dale: Absolutely!  I've left out all sorts of intermediate steps.  I haven't explained how those pressure sensitive nerves work, or how action potentials from them are transmit transmitted to the brain, how neurotransmitters are released to cross synaptic junctions, or how all this is integrated in the brain to produce the subjective qualia that I interpret as pressure on my butt.  Heck, I haven't even tried to explain why there's an "I" to do the interpreting :-)  So either I'm an abject failure, or all this is, like your crap comments, irrelevant.

Comment: @jamesqf all of those other intermediate steps you mention are indeed necessary for the sensation. So they do qualify as necessary causes. Gravity is not necessary as shown above. So it does not qualify as a necessary cause. Do you understand the concepts of necessary and sufficient? Gravity is neither. You do not feel gravity. Furthermore, you can simplify the scenario to use an accelerometer rather than a human. The conclusion remains. Gravity causes neither accelerometer readings nor butt sensations. It is not necessary for either

Comment: @Dale: You're still playing really stupid language games here.

Answer (score 4):

> You don't feel this backwards/upwards force with gravity.

You have this a little confused. In an accelerating car from the car’s non-inertial frame there is a contact force pushing forward and an inertial force pushing backward. In the ground’s frame there is a contact force pushing upward and a gravitational force pulling downward.

So the analogy is between the gravitational force and the inertial force. Thus you should say “you don’t feel this backwards/**downwards** force with gravity”. The backward inertial force for the car is analogous to the downward force of gravity, not the upward contact force.

In both cases the feeling is analogous. The easiest way to see that is to examine accelerometers. An accelerometer in the car detects the forward acceleration from the contact force only and not the backward inertial force. Similarly, an accelerometer on the ground detects the upward acceleration from the contact force only and not the downward gravitational force. Inertial/gravitational forces are not “felt”. What you feel in both cases is only the contact forces.

Comment: I think that's where my confusion comes from. So if we know that in the spaceship/car example the real force is the one in the direction of the contact force, doesn't that mean that gravity is just an inertial force and the earth is actually moving upwards (and we feel an inertial force, i.e. gravity, downwards, and a contact force with the ground pushing upwards)?

Comment: @Veirian said “doesn't that mean that gravity is just an inertial force and the earth is actually moving upwards”. Yes, exactly. This is the famous equivalence principle.

Comment: In Newtonian Mechanics does that mean that gravity just behaves differently from the force on the spaceship? I think my confusion stemmed from the fact that gravity seems to behave differently than other forces (like the force acting on the ship). In this case I'm just asking about Newtonian Mechanics, I understand gravity is not considered a force in GR and a weightless frame is an inertial frame according to it.

Answer (score 2):

You **do** feel gravity. I dont know if you ever been in a zero gravity situation (skydiving, a rollercoaster, jumped to the water off a big jump etc), but those situations are exactly what you should feel if you were in outer space. Indeed, astronauts in ISS are constantly in a free fall. So the answer is that you do feel gravity, its just that you are very used to it.

I don't know what you would feel of you were that tall, it's difficult to imagine! But you may feel [tidal forces](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force) along your body depending on how tall you are and how you are oriented with respect to the body.

---

Edited for your comment:

@Veirian, indeed that's correct, you are not missing anything. You **cant** distinguish the gravitational pull from earth from that of an accelerating body (assuming no tidal forces are around: i.e. in a sufficiently small volume). When you are standing on Earth, you feel a force of 1g, you might not be moving but you are surely accelerating for a non accelerated motion (free fall) would be an elliptical orbit around Earth. But you are standing still! Hence you are not on free fall and thus are experiencing an acceleration away from Earth, identical to that of a rocket at 1g.

Comment: Thanks! What I'm confused about is that in a spaceship accelerating forwards you feel a push from the back wall of the ship which to you would essentially feel exactly the same as gravity (if the ship accelerates at 1G). On earth you also feel a contact force from the Earth that pushes you up (otherwise you'd fall through to the core of the Earth). So in both cases you feel a contact force pushing up but in the space ship's case this force is in the same direction as the ship's acceleration, while on earth it's in the opposite direction of gravity. What am I missing?

Comment: You don’t feel gravity. The force of gravity on the astronauts in the ISS is almost as strong as it is here on earth. Their feeling of weightlessness is due to the absence of other forces, not the absence of gravity (since it isn’t absent)

Comment: Gravity is not a force (i.e. a cause), so your answer is misleading. Gravity is an effect, caused by a structural change identified by Einstein. There is the illusion of a 'pull' force, but what is really causing the effect is a variation in inertia (the coupling charge between a particle and the structure of spacetime), which is modified by the presence of mass on a planetary scale or greater. By modifying the structure of spacetime, mass reduces its resistance to motion. Nothing "pulls" on the particle, but a pathway is created, one requiring lower energy than motion in any other direction.

Comment: Veirian -- You have mixed up two entirely different concepts. The effect you feel if a spacecraft accelerates is caused by that acceleration: the rocket motors accelerate the deck plates they are connected to, and if you are standing on that deck, the deck accelerates you. If you are standing on the Earth, nothing accelerates you: the motion of the Earth is constant, so you are not being accelerated. I cannot explain Einstein's theory in two paragraphs, but it should at least be clear to you that the answer to your confusion is that the one case is due to acceleration and the other is not.

Comment: @Veirian In both cases, you're actually feeling electromagnetic forces between the molecules of the surface of the floor and the molecules of the soles of your feet.  In the spaceship, the floor is pushed into you by the engines.  On Earth you are pushed into the floor by gravity.  From your perspective, they are indistinguishable.

Comment: @Ed999 Yeah I think that might be it. If you only consider Newtonian Mechanics (so not Einstein's theory) would gravity be considered a force, and if yes would it be different from say the force pushing the spaceship? You feel a force downwards with gravity which means the real acceleration (or force) should be upwards (which is the case when you are in the spaceship) but gravity is considered to point downwards? Gravity seems to act the same way the fictitious force due to your inertia on the ship would, but it's considered a real force?

Comment: @Ryan_L Yeah I understand they are indistinguishable to you, but in Newtonian Mechanics are they considered different? 
Because gravity acts downwards and you feel the force pulling you downwards, while on the ship you feel a force downwards (due to your inertia) but the real force is upwards? So it seems that gravity behaves differently than other forces like the one accelerating the ship.

Comment: @Veiran No, in Newtonian mechanics both situations are also indistinguishable. You cant perform any experiment to determine whether or not you are on Earth or on an accelerating spaceship. It is only the realisation that free falling trajectories are indistinguishable with the absence of forces that Newtonian gravity separates from Einsteinian gravity. That is, in Newtonian mech. when you fall you accelerate with 1g, in General relativity you are actually under free motion (free fall), which is as of now, the correct idea.

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian That's what confuses me, with gravity the real force is towards Earth and you feel the force towards Earth, while on a spaceship you feel a force towards the back of the ship but the real force is forwards. I understand what you feel is exactly the same, but don't the two forces behave differently?

Comment: @Veiran My point is that since both forces feel the same way, or more precisely, since you can't perform an experiment to distinguish the two forces you cannot possibly know in which case you are. Sure, in Newtonian gravity you could be either under the action of the force of gravity or under the re-action of an acceleration. Are they caused by a different mechanism? Sure, but that is not the important realisation: you could have also been wearing a charged suit and be under the action of an electric field! The important realisation is that, unlike with the electric field, you cannot

Comment: distinguish by means of any local experiment the accelerating ship from Earth's gravity. This is NOT the case as if you where under the action of an electric field for instance, you could prepare an experiment with opposite charges and observe that they accelerate in the opposite direction. You cannot possibly distinguish gravity from an acceleration locally. So the two forces behave identically (unlike with an electric caused force)  Does this answer your questions?

Comment: @Veirian My point is that, in both situations you're feeling the same thing.  In both situations you're feeling the EM forces from the floor.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is more psychology than physics.

There is never a moment that you are not subject to gravity so your adjustment to gravity is completely automatic, completely internalized.

When you are standing up your feet are compressed by the weight of your entire body. Your neck is compressed only by the weight of your head.

Conversely, when you balance yourself upside down then your neck has to support the weight of your entire body.

The difference is huge, but your feet do not complain about being compressed in the same way that your neck will complain. You kind of  know your feet are compressed, but you don't pay any attention to that.

To create 1 G of acceleration in horizontal direction you need some vehicle capable of 1 G of acceleration. Today's high performance cars are capable of that. If the car can go from 0 to 100 kph (60 mph) in less than 2.7 seconds then the car is pulling more than 1 G of horizontal acceleration.

Take a model that offers the option of folding down the rear seats to create sufficient space to lie down. Lie down on a roller so you are free to roll towards the front or the rear.

Then when the car changes velocity in one direction 1 G worth of accelerative force is applied to your feet, and in the other direction 1 G worth of accelerative force is applied to the top of your head.

Answer (score 2):

> You don't feel this backwards/upwards force with gravity.

To begin with, can you feel forces at all? What is it that you feel? You can feel pressure if something tries to deform your body slightly (or not very slightly), and this is typically caused by an outside force acting on you.

If the car is accelerating, it, including the back of the seat you’re occupying, is trying to increase its velocity while you’re trying to maintain your current velocity. So the back of the seat is pushing you, and you feel this pressure.

If the car is anywhere close to a massive body such as a planet, it’s trying to get closer to that body. If it’s on the surface of the planet, the surface is trying not to get deformed too much and not to let the car fall through it so it exerts upwards pressure on the car, which it, in turn, exerts on your buttocks.

So you feel the acceleration and the gravity in exactly the same way, i. e. you don’t feel them directly; and you feel their effects in exactly the same way, i. e. as pressure from the seat.

See other answers for how it would feel if the car is in fact not on the surface of a planet.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at balanced forces vs unbalanced forces. Gravity can be considere somewhat constant force that you counteract with your muscles, if I consider a person who is standing up they will feel a net force of zero, gravity is completely balanced by their leg and glutes muscles. When the car accelerates it generates a force via Newton 2nd principle $F = ma $. This force is literally the thing that pushes you forward. At this point you are no longer in an inertial reference frame (the sum of all forces is zero) so you will feel a backwards facing force, balanced only by your contact with the car's seat (which is generally speaking deformable).

If you were enormously tall your head would not feel any backwards force as gravity will always point downwards. That is to say that if gravity would not be constant on your body you would have a non null stress tensor that would be accounted to have stability and not collapse.

Answer (score 1):

> You don't feel this backwards/upwards force with gravity.

Ever been in a rollercoaster? That stomach feeling you get after your crest a hill at full speed and start dropping? That's gravity accelerating you.

It's the exact same feeling you get when being in an accelerating car. Just a different direction and intensity.

> What I meant was that in a spaceship for example that accelerates upwards you feel a force pulling you downwards, but on Earth even though gravity acts downwards you feel a force pulling you down, rather than one pushing you up.

You've misunderstood the purpose of the relativity example. The takeaway isn't that you feel an opposite force to what you should. The takeaway is that whether A pushes against B, or B pushes against A, both scenarios feel the same to A and B.

Therefore, to apply this analogy to Earth, you'd have to consider two scenarios, one where Earth is static and has gravity (= you push against the Earth) and one where there is no gravity but the Earth is accelerating in the direction you are (= Earth is pushing against you).

There is no "it feels like it's the other direction" sensation in the relativity example that would relate to your "gravity should feel like it's upwards" claim. I suspect you've glossed over the fact that in the different scenarios, *different objects* (i.e. either A or B, depending on the scenario) are the ones applying a force (in opposite directions).

> Is it because gravity acts on your whole body equally?

The only difference here is that gravity does not contort you or imbalance you, where an accelerating car might (e.g. your head tilting back). However, for any reasonable car ride, there is no difference between the car accelerating you and gravity accelerating you.

I suspect you're misunderstanding the "acceleration" part. When you're standing on the ground, you're not accelerating. When the car start going faster and faster (and so do you), *that* is acceleration. These are two different sensations because one is acceleration and the other is not.

But if I drop you from a great height, and you start falling downwards, that is the same feeling as if you're in a car accelerating at 9.8 m/s², because now both scenarios are a form of acceleration.

You cannot equate (and therefore directly compare) gravity's pull (while standing still on the ground) and the acceleration gravity's pull might cause (e.g. when not touching the ground). These are two different things, and you experience them differently.

> If you were enormously tall, would your head keep feeling this backward force as the gravity acting on your body would no longer be uniform?

The size you'd have to be for any such effect to become noticeable, you're already running into the issue that your head must move *more* than your feet, because you're moving around the Earth's surface while trying to remain level to it, which means that you're rotating your position as you move along the surface, and your head has to travel much more distance than your feet, so you're going to feel like you're off-balance.

This effect will completely overshadow a tiny difference in gravitational pull (you'd be surprised just how far out you have to go for it to meaningfully lower).

Answer (score 1):

Gravity can be described as a pure acceleration, and it is perceived at such. You'd feel 0G when in free fall and when flying at constant velocity in outer space, and you'd feel 1G when standing still on the ground. If, in addition, you accelerate forward in a car with 1G, your total acceleration would amount to ca. 1.4G.

However, whereas your body senses all sources of acceleration in the same way, it is not as well accustomed to non-gravitational accelerations, its non-zero derivatives and certain related sensor inputs, as it is to gravity. The change of feeling moreover intensifies when sensor signals do not meet with your expectations or each other, or when they have high derivatives.

As for your premise that the difference in perception of acceleration is caused by the fact that gravity applies to your body as a whole whereas the  acceleration in a car is the result of a contact force, it is not correct. The force balances are similar. In both cases the contact force is in equilibrium with an inertial force as the result of an acceleration of every point in your body. With gravity, the contact surface (when standing) is the bottom of your feet, on which a force is exerted equal to that required for accelerating every point in your body up with 1G. When accelerating in a car, the contact surface is mainly your back, on which a force is exerted equal to that required for accelerating every point in your body forward with the actual acceleration. The problem in your thinking might be related to a swap of cause and effect (gravity *causes* the reaction force; car acceleration *is caused* by the reaction force), even though Newtonian physics don't actually care about this. After all, force balances are about instantaneous equilibria: every action is also a reaction, and vice versa.

I'll break the main answer down in several points for the interested reader.

**The human body does in fact sense acceleration and thus gravity directly, in contrast to what most answers here claim.** 
I am surprised to read all the claims stating that humans cannot sense acceleration directly. This is incorrect. The [vestibular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vestibular_system) system, located behind your ears, allow you to directly sense accelerations. More specifically, it consists of the [otolith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otolith) and the [semicircular cannels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicircular_canals), which allow you to sense linear and rotational accelerations respectively. They help you balance, and they are responsible for making you feel nauseous after jerky rollercoaster rides. If you want to know how it feels like to have a malfunctioning vestibular system: get drunk*. And no, the vestibular system does not distinguish gravity from acceleration, for the fact that gravity is an acceleration. By combining the gravitational acceleration and that of a car, the amplitude of the acceleration vector increases and its orientation changes.

For your interest: 
There is another important sense in the human body of which many are not aware, namely [proprioception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprioception). It senses internal body kinematics and kinetics, using the golgi tendon organs in your muscles. They close the loop with muscle control. The role of proprioception in daily activities such as walking is very important and shouldn't be confused with touch. [Watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_4wxtSmIvI) short 2 minute video to understand how it's like to go around without proprioception.

**The human body is a master of sensor fusion, but it can be fooled.** 
Your central nervous system fuses many types of sensor signals *and* your anticipation/expectation/knowledge for purposes of understanding and controlling all sorts of activities. These sensor signals include touch, vision and the aforementioned acceleration and proprioception. When *you* hit the accelerator in your car, you'll feel relatively comfortable. Everything matches up: the acceleration, the compression in your seat, the vision and your own anticipation. Instead, when you are a co-driver, it will easier feel less comfortable, because you lack the anticipation.

For your interest: 
There are also situations where sensor signals do not match, which cause confusion and discomfort. Consider for example being in a parked train, and the train(s) next to you start driving. Your vision might make you think that you start moving, but your vestibular, touch and proprioceptive senses disagree, causing you to feel discomfort up to the point that you realise that your sensor fusion made a mistake. These illusions of self-motion are well known and called [vection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusions_of_self-motion). The initial mistake occurs because your sense of vision is typically given more value. That said, your sensor fusion system can actually filter a non-matching sensor signal quite well. This has allowed for inventions such as flight simulators to feel realistic. The vision, sound, surrounding (realistic cockpit) and seat compression as caused by slightly tilting the platform all make you think that you are flying a plane. The only missing aspect is the actual linear acceleration (although not entirely, because the platform can move back and forth several meters, and mimic vibrations such as those caused by turbulence).

**Over the long haul, the human body is a master of adaptation.**
So why is it then, that we feel the effects of accelerating in a car more prominently (even if we hit the accelerator ourselves) than, say, walking? Let's put this to the extreme, why do we feel discomfort or excited, when jumping out of an aircraft? After all, the inputs match up: we have vision, we feel the acceleration (or actually, the lack thereof when jumping from the plane), we feel the air drag and we hear it too. Last but not least, we anticipated it (it was your own choice, nobody pushed you). The answer is simply that **we are not used to it**. Other than a counter-intuitive mental state for the case of jumping (our instinct didn't quite teach us that it would be a good idea to jump several kilometers down), our bodies are physically adapted to the presence of a ca. 10m/s^2 downward acceleration: our gravity. You can thank evolution for this. For the same reason, we have no problem being around in a pressurized environment of ca. 100MPa: our atmospheric pressure (rather the contrary, you'll not feel at comfort at all if you take that pressure away...). It exerts a force similar to the Earthly weight of ca. 10 Renault Twingos per square meter of surface, but our body does too in the opposite direction, and our touch sensors are trained to ignore their mutual presence. Same for acceleration: not only does the orientation change, but also the amplitude (0 for a free fall and >1 when accelerating a car). Worse than the difference, is the change: the vestibular organ is not particularly keen on change of acceleration, known as jerk.

For your interest: 
That said, whereas the human body has gone through a long optimization process as caused by evolution, it is still very well capable of adapting over a much shorter time interval than that of a life time, within a certain window of capabilities. Astronauts are capable of adapting to a 0G environment after a while (although it is not healthy for them), and you might be familiar with the human's capability to develop sea legs when sailing on a boat for long enough, etc.

<sub>* I cannot be held responsible for any effect this experiment might have.</sub>

Comment: (+1) That was actually required! Don't know why people here are just believing that human body cannot perceive accelerations. That's totally weird and unintuitive!

Comment: I'm still unsure about whether humans feel acceleration, or just forces. Consider a case where you're sitting in a chair on earth and feel the 1G reaction force pushing against your butt, while remaining stationary with zero acceleration. From an acceleration perspective, this is indistinguishable from floating in deep space, still having zero acceleration, but experiencing no forces whatsoever. Both cases have zero acceleration, but will feel very different. If humans *only* sensed acceleration, those cases would feel identical.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie An acceleration sensor does not distinguish a gravity from an "ordinary"  acceleration; it does not measure acceleration with respect to an inertial body like Earth. It will sense the same acceleration while sitting on Earth as sitting on a 1G forward acceleration platform in space, for which you'll feel the same force pressing against your butt. If it helps for you to think using Earth as a fixed reference frame, what the sensor measures on Earth is *a+g* instead of just *a* (*a* being your acceleration w.r.t. Earth, and *g = ~10m/s^2* the gravitational acceleration of Earth).

Comment: I just stumbled on the concepts of *proper* and *coordinate* acceleration, which I think explains it. Coordinate acceleration is with respect to some observer, so there is really no concept of zero coordinate acceleration in all frames. Proper acceleration, on the other hand, is with respect to the local gravitational field. It seems humans can feel *proper* acceleration, but not coordinate acceleration, since that depends on the observer. My chair-space example has identical coordinate acceleration, but different proper acceleration, which explains the difference in how it feels.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not 100% sure about this, but I think that in your example with the car you actually feel not the acceleration or deceleration as such, but the change of the acceleration or deceleration rate. If you would drive with a constant acceleration on a straight line for a while, you would adjust to it and feel it in exactly the same way as you feel the gravity.

Answer (score 0):

You can not feel gravity as such because, as you said. it acts on every atom in your body. What you feel is the stress set up in your body when an external contact force (effectively the electrostatic force) is applied either to accelerate you or counteract the gravitational force.

Answer (score 0):

You do feel gravity the same way as acceleration. That was Einstein‘s Point with the elevator thought experiment. The reason you cannot tell the difference between being in a rocket or a closed room on earth it’s because they feel the same.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of four reasons why a car's acceleration feels different:

1. Its changing. You're used to gravity and so it feels "normal" and you don't notice it. A car's acceleration changes as it goes into and out of curves, and so it's a constantly new stimulus, so you notice it more.
2. It's directed in a non-downward direction. You're used to gravity acting downwards, but you're not used to a sideways force, so it stands out to you.
3. The cues from your other senses make it more noticeable. Gravity isn't tied to motion, but a car's acceleration is. When you both feel acceleration and see yourself moving, it registered more strongly.
4. The total acceleration is higher. You're used to a certain amount of "weight", and your effective weight is higher when you're experiencing both gravity and a car's acceleration,  and you experience the additional acceleration as being notable.

Answer (score -1):

gravity and acceleration feel the same to humans.

so you do in fact feel it.